# Omnisharp fails to load standard C# project in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I'm trying to work on a standard C# (.Net 4.5.2) console app in Visual Studio Code as described [here](http://selfishdeveloper.blogspot.com/2016/12/who-says-you-can-use-visual-studio-code.html).
When Omnisharp starts to load I get the following warning: `"Some projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more details."`
If I look into the log I see this:

> [ERROR:OmniSharp#ProjectFileInfo] The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

Being on a Windows 10 machine I already have .Net Framework 4.6.2 installed and I don't want to downgrade my .Net Framework just for the sake of one project. If I change the target framework in .csproj manually (`<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>`) I get the same error 
just that that now `".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2"` is the one that cannot be loaded. 
Now, either the error message is not the appropriate one and whatever I do Omnisharp will not load a C# project (other than .Net Core) or something else is going on.

Does Omnisharp work with other versions of .Net than .Net Core? If yes, how can I solve my issue?

Comment: I've had the same issue. And I've seen that the problem also occurs with `dotnet build` (.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.3)). Hasn't anyone found a solution?

Comment: Looks related to https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1333